# How to Reduce with paste function with different seperator

Tags: r

For the following operation:

```
avector<-c("p1","p2","p3")
Reduce(paste,avector)
## "p1 p2 p3"
```

I want to get `"p1.p2.p3"`
Which is applying the paste function in `Reduce` with separator `"."`
Please advice.

Comment: `paste(avector, collapse = '.')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `paste(avector,collapse = ".")`